# Атрибут без поля в модели Django

Tags: django

Необходимо в экземпляре модели хранить атрибут `status` без добавления поля.
Атрибут необходим только для логики программы.

```
class ProcessErr(models.Model):
    OK = 0
    CONTINUE = 1
    EXIT = 2
    process_name = models.CharField('Наименование процесса', max_length=50,
            null=False, blank=False)
    status = ProcessErr.OK
```

В обычном классе я бы использовал

```
self.status = ProcessErr.OK
```

Декоратор `@property` во всех найденных примерах используется для вычислении с использованием обычных полей моделей.

Comment: Ничто не мешает вам использовать обычные поля и в моделях - `status = OK`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev. При этом значение 'status' будет доступно и сохранено в экземпляре класса?

Comment: Да, будет. Django обработает только дескрипторы, а обычные поля ему безразличны.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev. А если хочу обновлять 'status' в методах класса, к нему обращаться как 'self.status = self.OK'?

Comment: Можно так. Или так `self.status = ProcessErr.OK`

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам `status = ProcessErr.OK`?

Можно просто обратится к `ProcessErr.OК` вне модели, и внутри модели через `self.OK`

Comment: 'OK' это константа, она никогда не меняется, а 'status' это переменная которая указывает на статус данного экземпляра, поэтому мне и нужен 'status'.

Comment: Изначально сам вопрос появился из-за незнания мат.части работы интерпретатора python/ Почему то я думал, что атрибуты объявленные на уровне класса, недоступны через экземпляр класса. Исследования показали, что атрибуты класса еще хранят уникальные значения для каждого экземпляра. И это никак не связано с django. Это было для меня открытие.